# Why does oauth protocol use two steps to retrieve access_token instead of doing it in just one?

Tags: oauth-2.0

I am trying to understand how oauth protocol works. The books says that it involves two steps, when the end user first provides login information, the api provider returns a access code, and then another call is made to api provide with the access code and then we get the access token.

My question is that why can't the api provider returns the access token in steps when we it returns the access code instead? Why does it return first the access code and then the access token?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically to keep the access token out of the user's browser, where it is at higher risk of getting stolen or lost.

The [authorization code flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.1) that you are describing was originally meant to get the token to a web application hosted on a server. The web application would get the auth code from the browser and would need a special secret to exchange that code for an access token. This flow also allowed the web application to obtain a refresh token it could use to get new access tokens without the user's interaction.

The [implicit flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.2) would return the access token directly to the browser. It is considered unsafe and is deprecated in OAuth 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

There's an RFC about the implementation of OAuth here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3